# nil in gdb is not defined as 0x0?

Tags: objective-c, gdb, null

I was stepping through some simple Objective-C code with gdb (inside of Xcode) and noticed something strange.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
NSString *s = nil;
int x = (s == nil);
```

As I'd expect, the value of `x` after these two lines is `1`.  Strangely, if I try something similar in gdb, it doesn't work the same:

```
(gdb) print ret
$1 = (NSString *) 0x0
(gdb) print (int)(ret==nil)
$2 = 0
(gdb) print nil
$3 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x167d18 <nil>
```

It seems like gdb has some definition for nil other than what objective-C uses (0x0).  Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your code is being compiled, `nil` is a preprocessor constant defined to be either `__null` (a special GCC variable that serves as `NULL`), `0L`, or `0`:

```
<objc/objc.h>
#ifndef nil
#define nil __DARWIN_NULL /* id of Nil instance */
#endif

<sys/_types.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define __DARWIN_NULL __null
#else /* ! __GNUG__ */
#ifdef __LP64__
#define __DARWIN_NULL (0L)
#else /* !__LP64__ */
#define __DARWIN_NULL 0
#endif /* __LP64__ */
#endif /* __GNUG__ */
#else /* ! __cplusplus */
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

So, where does the `nil` that gdb picks up at runtime come from? You can tell from the message gdb gives that `nil` is the name of a variable located at that address:

```
(gdb) p nil
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x20c49ba5da6428 <nil>
(gdb) i addr nil
Symbol "nil" is at 0x20c49ba5da6428 in a file compiled without debugging.
```

Its value, unsurprisingly, turns out to be `0`:

```
(gdb) p *(long *)nil
$2 = 0
(gdb) x/xg nil
0x20c49ba5da6428 <nil>: 0x0000000000000000
```

Where does this variable come from? GDB can tell us:

```
(gdb) i shared nil
  3 Foundation        F -                 init Y Y /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation at 0x20c49ba5bb2000 (offset 0x20c49ba5bb2000)
```

Indeed, when we check the symbols defined in Foundation, we find `nil`:

```
$ nm -m /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation | grep nil$
00000000001f4428 (__TEXT,__const) external _nil
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pointing to the address in memory, not the variable contents.