# Local variables set to nil? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, null, static-variables

I'm reading a book on Objective-C and the author said that if local variables aren't assigned a value they will be set to nil, but static variables will be set to zero. So, I set up `int a` and didn't assign it a value. Then `NSLog(@"%i", a)` to display it and `a` was displayed as zero. I was a little confused on that and I was wondering if someone could clarify it for me?

Comment: If the book said that as you've written it, I would recommend tossing it in the trash and finding a different book.   Nil and 0 are effectively synonymous.  Local variables (save for object references under ARC) will be undefined.  Static and instance variables will be nil/zero/NULL/Nil, which are synonymous.

Comment: Agreed with bbum; that's terrible. What the hell is this book? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726817/can-variables-be-set-randomly-when-declaring-them-again/9726948#9726948

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With ARC enabled, your Objective-C object pointer variables will be set to nil regardless of where you create them.

Without ARC, and for built in C types, your variables will not be initialized.

Instance variables of Objective-C objects are always set to 0 (or nil) when you allocate an object.

Statics are set to 0.

I've gotten in the habit of always giving a default value to variables, though. It's been a good habit to have.

Comment: What about C types with ARC? What about if I have a BOOL when using ARC? Thanks!

Comment: @Ricardo they should be handled according to C rules. Statics will be 0 and all others should be considered garbage.

Comment: Thanks. So, something like @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL flag; is gargabe, isn't it? because is not staitc. However in my app I see it's 0 always. I don't have these rules very clear.

Comment: @Ricardo the property is backed by an instance variable, not a local variable. So it falls into the instance variable rule and will be set to 0/FALSE/nil.

Comment: For anyone looking for a source to this answer see Apple's document Transitioning to ARC Release Notes. Specifically the section titled Stack Variables Are Initialized with nil.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 13):

No<sup>2</sup>. Just as in "plain" C, local variables are *not* assigned a default value. (Although you may get lucky the first time part of the stack is used: *do not* rely on this!.)

Anyway, `nil` *is* 0<sup>1</sup> -- that is, `nil == 0` is always true -- so `NSLog("@%i", nil)` says "hey, log the argument as an integer", which is ... 0.

Happy coding.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [nil in gdb is not defined as 0x0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130325/nil-in-gdb-is-not-defined-as-0x0) which covers the technical definition, including the Objective-C++ case, in more detail. Note that the type changes depending upon architecture as well so `"@%i"` could very well be *wrong* for a particular system.

<sup>2</sup> See wbyoung's answer for *ARC-specific* rules.

Comment: Does the same thing go for static variables? Since, the author said that assigning zero to static variables would be redundant because their default value is zero.

Comment: With ARC enabled, objects are.

Comment: @stumped: Yes, `static` variables are intialized to 0.