# Value of loop variable after "for in" loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is the value of the loop variable in a `for - in` loop guaranteed to be `nil` after the loop executes, as long as the loop does not contain a `break` statement? For example, I'd like to write code like the following:

```
NSArray *items;
NSObject *item;
for (item in items) {
   if (item matches some criterion) {
      break;
   }
}
if (item) {
   // matching item found. Process item.
}
else {
   // No matching item found.
}
```

But this code depends on `item` being set to `nil` when the `for` loop runs all the way through with no `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use this:

```
id correctItem = nil;
for (id item in items) {
    if (item matches some criteria) {
        correctItem = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: with arc all is nilled automatically

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to check the array objects passing a specific test instead. You seem to break on the first occurrence so I only get one index back as well. If you want all matches you could use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` instead.

```
NSUInteger index = [items indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (/* check the item*/) {
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    // no match was found
} else {
    // at least one item matches the check
    id match = items[index];
}
```

Comment: with arc all is nilled automatically

Comment: This looks good, thanks, but it looks like you have to set the value of matchingItem when breaking, as in bneely's answer.

Comment: @Daij-Djan You are right that it's probably safe to assume ARC nowadays but I still feel that it's good practice. Still good to point out that are will set it to nil for you.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist My comment referred to an earlier version of your answer in which the variable "matchingItem" appeared. It seems you've edited it out, so my comment no longer applies.

Comment: @WillNelson Oh, sorry. I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 1):

> With ARC enabled, your Objective-C object pointer variables will be set to nil regardless of where you create them.
>   [<sub>[Source]</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022295/916299)

If you are not using ARC, you can assign the pointer to nil explicitly:

```
NSArray *items;
NSObject *item = nil;  //<- Explicitly set to nil
for (item in items) {
   if (item matches some criterion) {
      break;
   }
}
if (item) {
   // matching item found. Process item.
}
else {
   // No matching item found.
}
```

---

I don't know the exact case, but couldn't you just do this, doing the work *inside* the for loop:

```
NSArray *items;
NSObject *item; //Doesn't really matter about item being set to nil here.
for (item in items) {
   if (item matches some criterion) 
   {
       // matching item found. Process item.
      break;
   }
}
//Don't have to worry about item after this
```

Comment: Why would you want/need/care about setting `item = nil`, with or without arc, when you're about to reassign it with `for (item in items)` ?

Comment: Items may contain no objects.