# Pointer to Error-Pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, error-handling

Sorry, if found a lot of threads like the but they were not about this Error**-thing.

I tried to 'design' my methods like the error-examples I found. But calling the second,  the error is not pointing to nil, the debugger says `error: summary string parsing error`.

This is my controller-method:

```
-(void) refresh {
  NSError *error;
  ServerApi *serverApi = [mainModel newServerApi];
  NSArray *newItems = [serverApi getNewItems: &error];
  ...
```

This is the called method:

```
- (NSArray *) getNewItems: (NSError **) error {
  // Breakpoint here, error is: 'error: summary string parsing error' 
      ...
  NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: error];
```

I thought, I did the same as Apple with `sendSynchronousRequest...`. Their comment tells

```
error     Out parameter (may be NULL) used if an error occurs
             while processing the request. >>>>Will not be modified if the 
             load succeeds.<<<<
```

What did I do wrong and why does this work for Apples `sendSynchronousRequest...`?

Comment: how are you printing `error` in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to set your pointer to nil in `refresh`:

`NSError *error = nil;`

Also, remember, your checks should be:

- Checking `(*error)` for `nil` (aka "there was no error passed") - operation may or may not have been successful;
- Checking `error` for `NULL` (aka "there was no `NSError*` pointer passed, so don't assign it an object").

Comment: under ARC `error` will be initialized to `nil` automatically.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Are you sure? Only instance variables are initialized, if I remember correctly. We had some issues with uninitialized error pointers, and it was after moving to ARC.

Comment: pretty sure, but I'll find a reference.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Cool thx. Still good practice to initialize in my opinion.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022025/local-variables-set-to-nil-objective-c. Anyway still a good practice, but that's not cause of any problem under ARC.

Comment: @Leo Natan - Thx a lot, checking (*error) was my bad. The debugger with it's wrong information about 'error' did the rest ;-)

Comment: @Sammy Yes, I am aware of debugger bugs with pointer to pointer. Recently, I came to prefer the `errorBlock:` pattern instead of `NSError**`. More elegant and less error-prone.

Comment: Ok, ErrorBlock is an other option. But as I have some deeper method-stacks, I should test for *error correctly anyway. Thx

Comment: @Sammy checking for error is not the right way of applying this pattern. You should have the method to return a `BOOL` indicating whether the computation was successful and check the return value. Even some Apple APIs may fail and yet return a `nil` error, so avoid doing that!

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella - the original meaning of that method is to provide items, read from an server-api, so I think it should return them. An other thing is, that the server has to be addressed multiple times in this case (I simplified this a bit), so I do a lot of calls to convenience-methods. The error-pointer is the only way (I saw) to pass back an error up the call-stack.

Comment: @Sammy leaving aside the fact that you really should do this asynchronously, you can easily return a `BOOL` and return the items indirectly (in the same way you do with the error).

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella: I know, that you should normally do that call asynchronous. But my app only works in the own wlan, so there should be no long-running connections. Anyway, there's nothing the user can do since he was once connected to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine, as `error` does not need to be initialized "from outside".

Also, if you use ARC [it will automatically initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022025/local-variables-set-to-nil-objective-c) local object pointers to `nil`, so

```
NSError *error;
```

is no different than

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

**under ARC**.

While explicit initialization is still a good practice, that's not the source of any error here.

That being said,

> summary string parsing error

is a `lldb` error. My hypothesis is that it gets confused by the double pointer, but I wouldn't worry too much.

By the way, you're doing a slight mistake in implementing this pattern.
Synchronous methods that may fail, should method to return a `BOOL` value indicating whether the computation was successful and then clients will check that value and subsequently inspect the `error` object in case it failed.

Checking the `error` object is in general a bad idea: even some Apple APIs can fail and yet return a nil error, so avoid doing that!

Comment: it is fine under non arc too .. the error may not be nil. thats totally fine. LLDB then obviously cant show it but thats no real problem

Comment: Thx, so I don't have to ask about the debugger-info.
The check was my problem (see Leo Natan's answer).

Comment: @Daij-Djan Under non-ARC, if the `error` variable is not zeroed, you would not be able to tell if an error occurred or there was a garbage value.

Comment: @LeoNatan: Checking the error object to determine success is contrary to [Cocoa convention](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1). The direct return value should be used for that, and the error inspected only on failure.