# Why objective-c NS_ENUM variable automatically have default value

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I created an enum like this

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PermissionStages) {
    thePermissionNotDetermine = 0,
    thePermissionDenied = 1,
    theReminderPermissionAllowed = 2,
};
```

And create a variable like this

```
PermissionStages PermissionStageVar;
```

I have not assign any value to it, but by default this `variable` has `PermissionStages enum` first value, in this case its `thePermissionNotDetermine`

Why is this behavior?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of enums. You know in computer science 0 is a meaningful value in contrast to real world. You better assign a value of -1 to the undermined case.

Comment: The initial value could be different depending on where you are creating that variable.  Local variables aren't automatically defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
PermissionStages PermissionStageVar;
```

is getting a default value of `0`. This is similar to the line:

```
NSString *foo;
```

resulting in `foo` having an initial value of `nil`. Or

```
BOOL aBool;
```

resulting in `aBool` having an initial value of `NO`.

The variables are all initialized to a value of "0".

Since your enum happens to have a value with `0`, your variable appears to be initialized with `thePermissionNotDetermine`.

Comment: is there any way to initialize PermissionStageVar with some other  default value other then these, and which I don't use in code accept assigning as default value?

Comment: `PermissionStages PermissionStageVar = (PermissionStages)-1;` would be a way to force it to some other value. I don't recommend it though. The enum should only reference actual valid values.

Comment: local variables are not initialized to 0, with the exception of objective-c object references. So if your local BOOL has an initial value of NO, that is just a happy accident. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022025/local-variables-set-to-nil-objective-c